# JavaScript DRY Object Constructors

Tags: javascript, prototype, dry, factory

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
var myObj = {
  _fooCon: function(f) {
             if (typeof f != 'function') throw new TypeError('Bad Foo');
             this.fn = f;
           },

  _barCon: function(f) {
             if (typeof f != 'function') throw new TypeError('Bad Bar');
             this.fn = f;
           },

  someFoo: function(v) {
             return new this._fooCon(function(x) {
               return x + ' Foo ' + v;
             });
           },

  someBar: function(v) {
             return new this._barCon(function(x) {
               return x + ' Bar ' + v;
             });
           }
};
```

The reason for doing this is so I can use `instanceof` productively (i.e., so I can distinguish between the two objects, which are used in different scenarios, despite being structurally identical). (Ignore the fact that `someFoo` and `someBar` are similar!)

Is there a way I can abstract the constructor functions, so if I need to create, say, `_bazCon`, I don't need to repeat myself; or, if there's a bug, I don't have to fix every constructor definition?

I tried making a factory member, like this:

```
_factory: function(type, f) {
            if (typeof f != 'function') throw new TypeError('Bad ' + type);
            this.fn = f;
          }
```

...then:

```
_fooCon: function(f) { return new this._factory('Foo', f); }
```

Even without trying this, I can see it's not going to work! Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You would probably be better off designing your code to not use `instanceof` and instead use polymorphism so an object already contains the right methods for its type and no runtime checking is needed.  E.g. at object creation time, create the right type of object with the right type of methods.

Comment: Your first example is not clear, as you are explicitly sending a function and then checking for a function.  i.e. the check seems un-necessary...it's like saying  `// x=3;  // if (x===3);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions really do the same thing, then it's as simple as this:

```
var myObj = {
  _factory: function(err) {
                return function(f) {
                    if (typeof f != 'function') throw new TypeError('Bad ' + err);
                    this.fn = f;
                };
            },
  someFoo: function(v) {
             return new this._fooCon(function(x) {
               return x + ' Foo ' + v;
             });
           },

  someBar: function(v) {
             return new this._barCon(function(x) {
               return x + ' Bar ' + v;
             });
           }
};

myObj._fooCon = myObj._factory("Foo");
myObj._barCon = myObj._factory("Bar");
```

If there's other behavior that differentiates them, then you could have `_factory` receive a function argument that is invoked within the constructor. That function could use `.call` or `.apply` to set the `this` value to the object being constructed.

---

A different approach would be to use a constructor to create `myObj`, and take advantage of the variable scope so that you don't need to expose the `_xxxCon` constructors.

This uses an anonymous function as a constructor, since we don't need it again.

```
var myObj = new function() {
    var _factory = function(err) {
                return function(f) {
                    if (typeof f != 'function') throw new TypeError('Bad ' + err);
                    this.fn = f;
                };
            };

    var _fooCon = _factory("Foo");
    var _barCon = _factory("Bar");

    this.someFoo = function(v) {
             return new _fooCon(function(x) {
               return x + ' Foo ' + v;
             });
           },

    this.someBar = function(v) {
             return new _barCon(function(x) {
               return x + ' Bar ' + v;
             });
           }
};
```

You don't necessarily need the outer function to be used as a constructor, but you do need a function that returns an object to `myObj`.

If you *did* want to expose the `_xxxCon` functions, then change `var` to `this.`, and put the `this.` back in `someFoo` and `someBar`.